# List of projects with their lines of code data

Tags: metrics

Does anywhere in Web exist some site where you can find the list of different software projects and  applications with mentioned source lines of code indicators?
Or may be exist some academic papers with such kind of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For open source projects http://ohloh.net contains a lot of such data.

Comment: It is very strange for me of how they, for example, find out 2,330,253 lines of source code in ZF, if the git-repository head revision of ZF2 consists of just 275,208 including blank lines and comments...

Comment: It could be the case that ohloh is counting LoC from multiple sources, like repo branches and not only the trunk.

Comment: Ah, ok, but it is a bit confsing)

Comment: Supposing you are talking about http://www.ohloh.net/p/zend_framework, then you can check at http://www.ohloh.net/p/zend_framework/enlistments the multiple sources.

Answer (score 1):

Check various papers on software methodology, and follow the footnotes. Any methodology with even a nod to formalism will be based on some research of real, non-trivial projects.  These projects should be in the footnotes, and at least a few of them will be on the web.  In fact, some of the projects might just include the actual research in the appendices.

Try CiteSeer for starters.